# Name for elements from domain used in mapping

Tags: functions, terminology

As I understand, in a function, the subset of the codomain actually mapped to is called the range.

What about the domain? Is there a name for the subset of the domain actually used in a mapping?

Comment: A [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) or mapping uses every element of the domain.

Comment: It's called ... the domain.   *Every* element of the domain is mapped and you *always* use every single element.  You are not allowed to *ever* have an element unused.

Comment: Worth noting if you have a function such as $\frac 1{x-5}$ the domain is *NOT* $\mathbb R$.  The domain is $(-\infty, 5)\cup (5, \infty)$ (which can also be written as $\mathbb R\setminus \{5\}$.  That might be what is confusing.  A "real-value function" doesn't always mean the domain is all the real numbers; it just means the domain consists only of real numbers, or in other words the domain is a subset of the real numbers.

Comment: @fleablood A real-valued function is not a function whose domain is a subset of the real numbers, but a function that takes real values, that is, a function whose *codomain* is a subset of the real numbers.

Comment: @jjagmath  Same thing?  "but a function that takes real values" that is its domain consists only of real numbers.  But you may be right (in fact I think you are and I was wrong) that a real valued function *give* real values.  But would $f:\{fred, wilma\}\to \mathbb R$ so $f(fred) = \pi$ and $f(wilma)= -27$, would that be a "real-valued function" do you think.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, that's a real valued function. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-valued_function

Answer (score 1):

It's called ... the domain.

*Every* element of the domain is mapped and you *always* use every single element.  You are not allowed to *ever* have an element unused.

Worth noting if you have a function such as $\frac 1{x-5}$ the domain is *NOT* $\mathbb R$.  The domain is $(-\infty, 5)\cup (5, \infty)$ (which can also be written as $\mathbb R\setminus \{5\}$).  That might be what is confusing.  A "real-value function" doesn't always mean the domain is all the real numbers; it just means the domain consists only of real numbers, or in other words the domain is a subset of the real numbers.

Now, an incredibly reasonable question right now would be "why?".  Why can't we say that the domain of $f(x) =\frac 1{x-5}$ is all the real numbers but we don't use them all and why can't we call the terms we *do* use something like the "co-domain" or something?

Well, "because we say so" is always a fun answer (and it gets more fun the older you get) but I think the actual answer is that beggers the concept of domain.  If we include items that are *not* mapped to then that could include anything.  If we say that $5$ is in the domain even though it is never used we could ask "what about Babar the elephant? That's never used but neither is $5$ so why is $5$ in the domain but not Babar the elephant?"

======

Actually more technically:

If you have two sets $A$ and $B$ then *product* of the two sets is defined as  $A\times B = \{(a,b)|a\in A, b\in B\}$, that is the product is the set of all ordered pairs where the first term of a pair is an element of $A$ and the second term is an element of $B$.

We have a mathematical concept of a *relationship* of $A$ to $B$ is any subset of $A\times B$.

An example of a relationship could be, if $A=B=\mathbb R$ is "less than".   THe idea of mathematical object representing the concept of $x < y$ would be $\{(x,y)|x< y\}$.  This will include the pair $(2,3)$ and the pair $(2, \sqrt 7)$.  And the pair $(3, \sqrt 7)$ and $(3,4)$ and any infinite uncounted many others.  It would *not* include $(2,3)$ or $(3,2)$ or $(\sqrt 7, 2)$ etc. But note in this relationship we can have many pairs $(2,x)$ where the first term is $2$.  We have $(2,3), (2,2.7), (2,5)$ and an infinite number more.

A *function* is defined as a special kind of relation.  A function is a subset of $A\times B$ where $f = \{(x,y)| x\in A, y=f(x)\in B\}$.  The one thing that makes this a function is that:

> for each element $x\in A$ there is exactly one and only one pair $(x,y)=(x,f(y))$ where the first term is $x$.  Thus the entire domain must be specified to be all of $A$ and *each* term of $A$ is represented exactly once, no more, no less.

There is really no requirement on the second term except that for each $x$ the second term $f(x)$ must be unique to $x$.  Not all terms of $B$ need to be used.  But it is to understand that each term of the domain $A$ is used exactly once, everyone is used, and none is used twice or more, that defines a function.

Okay.... you may ask.  Well, why didn't we define a function that no element of the domain may be used more than once but not every element needs to be used at all?  Okay.... we could but that would have not been as precise or clear.  I guess this may be a "because we say so".

Comment: Thanks. So are you saying you can't have a function with domain and codomain of the integers with the following mapping: 1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 6? Are you maybe saying that for this function the domain can only be {1, 2, 3}? If so, it seems a bit strange that you can have unused codomain elements, but not unused domain elements. Maybe there's some logical reason why this must be so, which I have not yet understood.

Comment: As defined $\{(1,2), (2,4),(3,6)\}$ has a domain of $\{1,2,3\}$.  The co-domain has not been specified.  The actual reason is a function is a special type of relation and ... you know, I'll add that to my answer.  I really should have in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but here's an answer to what I think you're confused about.

Let's use examples so that it's easier to see it "in action"

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x} $ ; the **Domain** is $[0,+ \infty)$ but notice that $ [0,+ \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}=(- \infty , + \infty)$  the symbol "$\subset$" means "subset" and its kind of like $<$ but for sets! We say A is a subset of B if all elements of A are contained in B.

so in our exapmple with $f(x)=\sqrt x$ the **codomain** is $\mathbb{R}. 
$

The **Range** of a function $f$ is all the $y$ values in can take .

Let $g(x)=|x|$ the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ and the range is $[0,+ \infty)$

you can see it geometrically if you see the graph of $g$ as $x$ goes from $- \infty \to + \infty $,   $y$ only takes non-negative values.

If you have any more questions or you didnt understand something feel free to let me know and I'll be glad to help you out!

Comment: Ye miss-type I corrected it